# Error: No Such Partition, Grub Rescue

Tags: grubrescue, grub-legacy

I am a newbie to Ubuntu, on the top of that I am facing the following issue:

I recently deleted a 3GB partition on my Windows (which was empty), after which when I rebooted, I could not get to grub, instead I was landed at an Error:

```
Error: No such partition
Grub Rescue>
```

I immediately searched YouTube and accordingly enetered the following in the rescue CLI:

```
ls
ls (hd0,msdos7)
>>ext2 File System 
set boot=(hd0,msdos7)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

I now landed in grub bootloader!! and selected Windows 10, it successfully booted. I rebooted again to check if Ubuntu is booting... I again landed on the Grub Rescue CLI, did the same process again, and I was again in grub bootloader and I booted Ubuntu.

EVERYTHING IS WORKING FINE but I am landing at the GRUB RESCUE CLI each time I boot my Laptop.

Please Help, ASAP!

Comment: Make sure you have both a Windows repair/recovery flash drive and Ubuntu live installer. You show msdos/MBR partitions, so only have grub in MBR (or Windows). Grub only boots working Windows & periodically after Windows updates grub will not boot it as it has turned fast start up back on. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It looks awkward to answer my own question, but for others who have the same problem, this is how I tackled the problem:
I booted into Ubuntu, in the terminal I wrote:
`sudo update-grub`
and hit the enter key, then the following command:
`sudo grub-install yourhd` where `yourhd` refers to your hard disk location for example:

- For `hd0`, `yourhd` = `/dev/sda`
- For `hd1`, `yourhd` = `/dev/sdb`
- For `hd2`, `yourhd` = `/dev/sdc`
- And so on...

In my case the code is hence:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then just reboot your PC and Good Day!

Reference: [grub rescue shows every time I open the pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113208/grub-rescue-shows-every-time-i-open-the-pc)